# how to connect bluetooth devices after turning bluetooth on?

Tags: bluetooth

This is in LXQT, I am apparently the dumbest person in human history but I have been digging through menus for like 45 minutes trying to connect my bluetooth headphones. I got as far as [image: this screen] where it's telling me that I turned Bluetooth on